# How to remove cookies under 1 domain in CookieContainer

Tags: c#

In `System.Net.CookieContainer`

if I want to remove all cookies under a domain name, how?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
CookieContainer c = new CookieContainer();
var cookies = c.GetCookies(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
foreach (Cookie co in cookies)
{
  co.Expires = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
}
```

This will expire all cookies for the domain you specify.

Comment: Actually you can just set the 'Expired' flag to true. It appears to be the *only* way to remove cookies from a CookieContainer/CookieCollection.

Comment: See the implementation: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Primitives/src/System/Net/CookieContainer.cs#L311