# Clear a CookieContainer

Tags: c#, httpclient

I want to clear all cookies in my CookieContainer. If I do this:

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
// make some requests
cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

Will the httpClient have the new (empty) cookieContainer, or I have to re-create my httpClient?

Comment: Yes. The cookies will be cleared.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne thanks!

Comment: This is incorrect; reassigning cookieContainer does not change the container referenced by the HttpClient with the code above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that you're updating the local reference, but not the reference to the CookieContainer in the HttpClientHandler. You can see in the answer below the only way to expire cookies in a CookieContainer, setting the Expires property to a past DateTime.

[How to remove cookies under 1 domain in CookieContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444087/how-to-remove-cookies-under-1-domain-in-cookiecontainer)

Creating a fresh HttpClient can also fix it if performance is not something you care about.

Answer (score 0):

he has a ref to the handler just do handler.CookieContainer = new();

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should [vote it up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).